# PHP find string into HTML text and replace it

Tags: php, regex

```
    $text = "<p>Pellentesque ac urna eget diam volutpat suscipit
     ac faucibus #8874# quam. Aliquam molestie hendrerit urna, 
    vel condimentum magna venenatis a.<br/> Donec a mattis ante. 
Ut odio odio, ultrices ut faucibus vel, #2514# dapibus sed nunc. In hac sed.</p>";
```

I need to search for #myid# string, and replace with `<a href='mylink.php?myid'>myid</a>`

How can I do?

Comment: str_replace but i don't like it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need regular expressions to do this, or are you planning to replace all 4 digit numbers (surrounded with #)??

If it's for a single ID, you could use:

```
$replace_id = 2514;

$replacement_find = "#{$replace_id}#";
$replacement_replace = "<a href=\"mylink.php?{$replace_id}\">{$replace_id}</a>";

$text_final = str_replace($replacement_find, $replacement_replace, $text);
```

---

If you're doing multiple replacements (or, as per comment, not knowing any IDs) you can use this:

```
$text_final = preg_replace('@#([0-9]+?)#@', '<a href="mylink.php?$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

---

EDIT: From your comment, you could use `preg_match_all` to get all IDs in an array that are contained within the string. In the following code, `$matches[1]` contains the value of everything within the `()`s in the regular expression, see return of `print_r`.

```
preg_match_all('@#([0-9]+?)#@', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

---

To accommodate your latest request, you can use `preg_replace_callback` to get what you want:

```
function callback($matches) {
        return '<a href="mylink.php?' . $matches[1] . '>' . getProductName($matches[1]) . '</a>';
}
$text_final = preg_replace_callback('@#([0-9]+?)#@', "callback", $text);
```

Comment: But he may not know the IDs in advance

Comment: Updated my answer with a simpler regex than Duniyadnd's to get the correct result, commented Duniyadnd's answer.

Comment: The `preg_replace` will automatically find/replace all matches. If you want to get them into an array you could use `preg_match_all`, yes: `preg_match_all('@#([0-9]+?)#@', $text, $matches); print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: and instead <a href="mylink.php?$1">$1</a> i need to get <a href="mylink.php?$1"> getNameProduct(myid) </a> ?? Is it possible??

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to use `preg_replace_callback` in this case!

Comment: This replace only my first link...!!

Comment: Ops. i miss quote into my code. IT WORK!!! u save me!!! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = preg_replace("/\#(\d+?)\#/s" , "<a href=\"mylink.php?$1\">$1</a>" , $text);
```

Comment: This will pull through the #s to the link aswell, fixed/alternate regex depending on what the OP requires is in my answer.

Comment: Ha - nice, I was updating it when your comment came in. Upvoted your comment. :)

Comment: @Duniyadnd, `preg_match` (if used) would actually only find the first occurrence of the regex then stop, `preg_match_all` will match them all. `preg_replace` will replace all occurrences like you said.

Comment: @rudi_visser - I'm an idiot, i was thinking preg_replace() while I was typing preg_match().

Comment: and instead <a href="mylink.php?$1">$1</a> i need to get <a href="mylink.php?$1"> getNameProduct(myid) </a> ?? Is it possible??

Comment: getNameProduct is afunction? or is that a string?